# Ist this the proper way to create a list from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a long `Array` which multiple `objects` (also similar `objects`) and I created this `code` to search and `print` it.
ist this a proper way? somehow it dosn't seem to be proper way to do this:

```js
    
var arr = [{
            "name": "first",
            "lastName": "1",
            "job": "backer"
        },
        {
            "name": "second",
            "lastName": "2",
            "job": "müller"
        },
        {
            "name": "Third",
            "lastName": "2",
            "job": "designer"
        }
    ];


    btn.onclick = function (e) {
var arrTwo = [];
        e.preventDefault();

        arrTwo.length = 0;
        txt.innerHTML = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt(inp.value) === parseInt(arr[i].lastName)) {
                arrTwo.push(`<p class="num"> <span>Number:</span> ${arr[i].lastName} <p class="name">
            <span> name: </span> ${arr[i].name} <p class="job"><span>Job</span>: ${arr[i].job}</p>
          `);
            }
        }

        ul = document.createElement('ul');
        txt.appendChild(ul);

let arrThree = arrTwo.filter((e, index) => {
return arrTwo.indexOf(e)=== index;
});

        
        arrThree.forEach(function (item) {
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            ul.appendChild(li);
            li.innerHTML += item;
        })
    }
```

```css
    span{
      color:red;
    }
```

```html
    <form action="submit" >
      <input type="number" id="inp">
      <button id="btn">search</button>
      </form>
    <p id="txt"></p>
```

with the For loop, I compare the value of the input with objects in my array and send it to the second Array (arrTwo). my Objects in the the First array have multiple Attributes so I filter them to print just one of my Object with the same (name). after that, I print it.

Comment: In vanilla JS, this is a reasonable way, but if you're doing a lot of these things, it quickly becomes difficult to maintain. That's why templating libraries like Mustache and Handlebars, and frameworks like React and Vue exist.

Comment: Of course this doesn’t need that second array, you can create the LI element, assign content to it, and append it to the UL inside your `for` loop already.

Comment: Don't write HTML as strings in JS, it's horrible to read and horrible to maintain. You're already using JS functionality to create elements. Use that for all of the instances where you need to create additional HTML. Whilst @Thomas is correct I encourage anyone to learn the base methods on how to do things like this first, then evolve to utilising templating libraries & such.

Comment: @CBroe I push the found Objects to a new Array, so I can filter the new array for the similer Objects.i have similar objects with different Attributes.

Comment: _“so I can filter the new array for the similer Objects”_ - in your `arrTwo.forEach`, there isn’t any filtering going on, you just create a list item for every array element. Therefor, you could have just created those list items directly inside the `for` loop above. The if condition there _is_ your filtering, so instead of pushing only the filtered elements to a new array, you might as well create the list items only for those filtered elements right there.

Comment: @CBroe actually before forEach methode, I filterd the arrTwo: "let arrTwo = arrTwo.filter((e, index) =>{ return arr.indexOf(e) === index; })"  and printed the arrTwo Array to the page. ;)

Comment: So you are checking whether the elements in that second array, are still at the same index they were at in the original array? Not sure what exactly the point of that is supposed to be, but then your question lacked a _proper_ explanation of what you actually want to achieve here in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I edithed the code, I hope now it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the logic seems to be not correct. Instead of creating `arrayTwo` and `arrayThree`, you could directly append the node into your dom. A simplified implementation looks something similar to this.

```js
var arr = [{
    "name": "first",
    "lastName": "1",
    "job": "backer"
  },
  {
    "name": "second",
    "lastName": "2",
    "job": "müller"
  },
  {
    "name": "Third",
    "lastName": "2",
    "job": "designer"
  }
];


btn.onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  txt.innerHTML = "";
  ul = document.createElement('ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(inp.value) === parseInt(arr[i].lastName)) {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = `<p class="num"> <span>Number:</span> ${arr[i].lastName} <p class="name">
        <span> name: </span> ${arr[i].name} <p class="job"><span>Job</span>: ${arr[i].job}</p>
      `;
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  }
  txt.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="submit">
  <input type="number" id="inp">
  <button id="btn">search</button>
</form>

<p id="txt"></p>
```